# Format of Row in VBA based on 1stCell and also Compare to above row?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2003

I was wondering how would i through VBA conditionally format the whole row or a row in a range based on the first cell in that row? Also it would require a comparison to the previous row to current row (first cell value) and format it as per its results?
I know how to do it with cells but rows in a range has me stumped. 
Also i already have a search criteria within conditional formatthing.

Answer (score 1):

You know how to do it will cells in a range, you just append the `.entirerow` to the end of the range e.g.-

`Cells(1,1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 6`